# Передача двух наборов аргументов в метафункцию

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Есть задачка:

Напишите метафункцию Zip (аналог std::transform), которая принимает два списка целых чисел одинаковой длины, а так же бинарную метафункцию, и возвращает список, получившийся в результате поэлементного применения метафункции к соответствующим элементам исходных списков.
Пример:

```
template<int a, int b>
struct Plus
{
    static int const value = a + b;    
};
 
// два списка одной длины
using L1 = IntList<1,2,3,4,5>;
using L2 = IntList<1,3,7,7,2>;
 
// результат применения — список с поэлементными суммами
using L3 = Zip<L1, L2, Plus>::type;  // IntList<2, 5, 10, 11, 7>
```

Даны IntList и InCons (IntCons позволяет увеличить список на один элемент — он добавляется в начало списка):

```
struct IntList;
 
template <int h, int... I>
struct IntList<h, I...>
{
    static const int Head = h;
    using Tail = IntList<I...>;
};
 
template<>
struct IntList<> {};
   
template <int value, class IL>
struct IntCons {};
 
template <int value, int... primes>
struct IntCons<value, IntList<primes...>>
{
    using type = IntList<value, primes...>;
};
```

Моё приблизительное решение:

```
template<int... L1, int... L2, template <int, int> class Op>
struct Zip;
 
template<int... val, int... val2, template <int, int> class Op >
struct Zip<IntList<val...>, IntList<val2...>, Op>
{
    using value = typename Op<IntList<val...>::Head, IntList<val2...>::Head>::value;
    using type = typename IntCons<value, Zip<IntList<val...>::Tail, IntList<val2...>::Tail, Op>>::type;
};
```

Естественно, не рабочее. Соответственно вопрос - каким образом можно передать два IntList'а в функцию Zip? Два набора аргументов передать невозможно. Что-то в духе
template<template<int... Values> class F1, template<int... Vals2> class F2, template <int, int> class Op>
struct Zip;
тоже не работает. Помогите пожалуйста понять синтаксис, который день к задаче возвращаюсь.

UPD: Задачка конечно же решалась крайне просто:

```
template<typename L1, typename L2, template<int, int> class Op>
struct Zip {
    using Next1 = typename L1::Tail;
    using Next2 = typename L2::Tail;
    using type = typename IntCons< Func<L1::Head, L2::Head>::value, typename Zip<Next1, Next2, Op>::type >::type;
};
 
template<template<int, int> class Op>
struct Zip<IntList<>, IntList<>, Op>{
    using type = IntList<>;
};
```

Comment: Я хочу уточнить: вам точно нужны "списки" времени компиляции?

Comment: Да, это задача из курса по С++.

Answer (score 3):

Не претендую на единственно-верное решение (или даже хорошее), но я бы сделал как-то так:

```cpp
// main.cpp

#include <iostream>

struct EmptyNode {
  const static size_t size = 0;
};

template <int Val, typename Tail>
struct MetaListImp {
  const static size_t size = Tail::size + 1;

  template <int Num>
  static constexpr int get() {
    static_assert(Num >= 0);

    if constexpr (Num == 0) {
      return Val;
    } else {
      return Tail::template get<Num - 1>();
    }
  }
};

template <int Val, int... Args>
auto makeList() {
  if constexpr (sizeof...(Args) != 0) {
    auto tail = makeList<Args...>();
    return MetaListImp<Val, decltype(tail)>{};
  } else {
    return MetaListImp<Val, EmptyNode>();
  }
}

template <int... Args>
struct MetaList {
  using type = decltype(makeList<Args...>());
};

template <int First, int Second>
struct Plus {
  const static int result = First + Second;
};

template <int Num,
          typename List1,
          typename List2,
          template <int, int>
          typename Op>
auto calc() {
  if constexpr (Num == List1::size - 1) {
    return MetaListImp<
        Op<List1::template get<Num>(), List2::template get<Num>()>::result,
        EmptyNode>{};
  } else {
    auto tail = calc<Num + 1, List1, List2, Op>();
    return MetaListImp<
        Op<List1::template get<Num>(), List2::template get<Num>()>::result,
        decltype(tail)>{};
  }
}

template <typename List1, typename List2, template <int, int> typename Op>
struct Zip {
  static_assert(List1::size == List2::size);

  using type = decltype(calc<0, List1, List2, Op>());
};

int main() {
  using first  = MetaList<0, 1, 2, 3, 4>::type;
  using second = MetaList<1, 2, 3, 4, 5>::type;

  using output = Zip<first, second, Plus>::type;
  std::cout << "size of output: " << output::size << std::endl;
  std::cout << output::get<0>() << std::endl;
  std::cout << output::get<1>() << std::endl;
  std::cout << output::get<2>() << std::endl;
  std::cout << output::get<3>() << std::endl;
  std::cout << output::get<4>() << std::endl;

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

А вообще я бы посоветовал вам посмотреть **boost::mpl** - библиотека как раз заточена на dimension *anlyzis*

UPD: усовершенствовал код:

```cpp
// main.cpp

#include <iostream>

struct EmptyNode {
  const static size_t size = 0;
};

template <int Val, typename Tail>
struct MetaListImp {
  using tail                   = Tail;
  static constexpr size_t size = Tail::size + 1;
  static constexpr int    val  = Val;
};

template <int Val, int... Args>
struct MetaListConstructor {
  static constexpr size_t tailLen = sizeof...(Args);
  using type = MetaListImp<Val, typename MetaListConstructor<Args...>::type>;
};

template <int Val>
struct MetaListConstructor<Val> {
  static constexpr size_t tailLen = 0;
  using type                      = MetaListImp<Val, EmptyNode>;
};

template <int... Args>
struct MetaList {
  using type = typename MetaListConstructor<Args...>::type;
};

template <int First, int Second>
struct Plus {
  static constexpr int result = First + Second;
};

template <template <int, int> typename Op, typename List1, typename List2>
struct ZipConstructor {
  using type = MetaListImp<Op<List1::val, List2::val>::result,
                           typename ZipConstructor<Op,
                                                   typename List1::tail,
                                                   typename List2::tail>::type>;
};

template <template <int, int> typename Op>
struct ZipConstructor<Op, EmptyNode, EmptyNode> {
  using type = EmptyNode;
};

template <typename List1, typename List2, template <int, int> typename Op>
struct Zip {
  static_assert(List1::size == List2::size);

  using type = typename ZipConstructor<Op, List1, List2>::type;
};

template <typename List>
void printMetaList() {
  if constexpr (List::size > 0) {
    std::cout << List::val << std::endl;
    printMetaList<typename List::tail>();
  }
}

int main() {
  using first  = MetaList<0, 1, 2, 3, 4>::type;
  using second = MetaList<1, 2, 3, 4, 5>::type;

  using output = Zip<first, second, Plus>::type;

  printMetaList<output>();

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Интересный очень подход, но решение сильно проще оказалось.

Comment: @Kiskers будет хорошо, если вы опубликуете ответ с вашим решением

Answer (score 3):

Вы как-то сильно переусложнили. Это делается вот так:

```
template <typename A, typename B, template <int, int> class Op>
struct Zip;
 
template <int ...A, int ...B, template <int, int> class Op>
struct Zip<IntList<A...>, IntList<B...>, Op>
{
    using type = IntList<Op<A, B>::value...>;
};
```